# Subtraction in JavaScript only returns two digits of the thousands

Tags: javascript, subtraction

I have two variables holding integer values:

```
x = 36,000;
y = 18,045.40;
```

this is how i subtract:

```
z = parseInt(x) - parseInt(y);
```

the result is 15.

If i remove the parseInt the result is 'Nan'.

How do I go about subtracting x with y without rounding off or removing thousands?

many thanks.

Comment: Don't gave commas in your value, also see this demo : [Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/FCeUR/) in which you have a idea to subtract two floating values even it is a positive or negative value...

Answer (score 6):

Don't put commas in your numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted won't even run.  I would recommend pulling the `,`s out of your numbers and using [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) instead.  This appears to give the result you want.  Demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yVWA9/

code:

```
var x = 36000;
var y = 18045.40;

alert(parseFloat(x) - parseFloat(y));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no separator for thousands in Javascript. Your variables are either holding strings and not integer values or you are getting syntax error.

If you have strings and they cannot be changed (like received from service, etc.) then try this:

```
x = "36,000";
y = "18,045.40";

// remove commas and convert to numbers
function norm(num) { return +num.replace(',', ''); }

console.log(norm(x) - norm(y));
```